# Getting Application Layout to work with Bootstrap4Xpages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages

I'm using Domino 9.0.1 and have managed to install correctly the Bootstrap Library 1.0.0.201403171254.

Under Application Configuration/Xsp Properties/General I have set the theme to be

```
bootstrapv3.1.1
```

and under Application Configuration/Xsp Properties/Page Generation. I have set up

```
com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library
org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.library
```

as needed XPages Libraries.

I'm having trouble making the Application Layout control work as I expected.

In the first tab, Application Layout, there is a drop-down with OneUI Application Configuration, Bootstrap Application Configuration, and Basic Application Configuration. I try to put the drop-down on Bootstrap Application Configuration, but it doesn't stick and the source still shows.

I've looked as a comparison to the demo databases and they have this  tag that I am expecting there too.

I'm not sure what to do.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
<xe:applicationLayout id="applicationLayout1">
    <xp:callback
        facetName="facetMiddle"
        id="facetMiddle">
    </xp:callback>
    <xe:this.configuration>
        <xe:oneuiApplication titleBarName="Schulungen">
            <xe:this.titleBarTabs>
                <xe:basicLeafNode label="Link 1"></xe:basicLeafNode>
            </xe:this.titleBarTabs>         
        </xe:oneuiApplication>
    </xe:this.configuration>
</xe:applicationLayout></xp:view>
```

Comment: I've not tried using app layout control like this yet but just to double check.  You installed it on the server and on designer right?

Comment: yes, it's installed on the server, in designer and also I've got the local web preview working (via the elegant 'copy-paste files from one obscure directory to another, almost identiacally named directory' method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a trick: go to All Properties and then remove the xe:oneuiApplication configuration under configuration by clicking the remove button next to xe:oneuiApplication:
[image]

You can then add a new configuration and select bx:bootstrapApplication:
[image]

Comment: yup, that was the one. I'm finding that there is an uneasy, co-dependant relationship between the Design and the Source tab. I think I would rather just have to edit text files, and have no ambiguity.