# how use 3.2.0 theme with BootStrap4Xpages?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

Hello I have downloaded the relase 2014-07-02 from [here](http://bootstrap4xpages.openntf.org/)

I know well bootstrap 3.2.X and I have some classic XPages with this integration.
My customer ask me now a rapid NSF application.
So I drag the "Application Layout Control" and select "BootStrap Application Configuration" but after that the souce code is worng

[image: choose app layout]

After press OK I don't see the special GUI menu that are into this slides number 27 [slideshare menu](http://www.slideshare.net/MarkLeusink/bootstrap4xpages-webinar-17-june-2014-tlcc-teamstudio) because the source is a normal OneUiLayout

```
<xe:applicationLayout id="applicationLayout2">
    <xe:this.configuration>
        <xe:oneuiApplication></xe:oneuiApplication>
    </xe:this.configuration>
</xe:applicationLayout>
```

I have installed too the lasted extensions library for 9.0.1 (901v00_09.20140903-1400)

I don't know..but is a GUI bug?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23784980/785061

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know about this behaviour, but haven't been able to fix it yet. After you've selected the `Bootstrap Application Configuration` object, you need to change the `xe:oneuiApplication` object to the `bx:bootstrapConfiguration` object. You can do that from the same dialog. Once you've done that you end up with:

```
<xe:applicationLayout
    id="applicationLayout1">
    <xe:this.configuration>
        <bx:bootstrapApplication
            pageWidth="full"></bx:bootstrapApplication>
    </xe:this.configuration>
</xe:applicationLayout>
```

That configuration object also allows you to set additional options specific to Bootstrap4XPages like 'navbarInversed' and 'pageWidth'.

Don't forget to set your theme to `bootstrapv3.2.0` if you want that version.

Comment: tnx you ...the theme is correct... this is a a bug of GUI, THANKS